# What does spawn ,expect and send command in linux/unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command, password-protection

The following three lines having three commands(spawn,expect,send), but what it does actually. Please explain any one

```
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no usr@$myhost.example.com'<br>
expect "password"<br>
send "$PWD\n" <br>
EOD
```

Comment: It starts an `ssh` session`, waits for it to ask for the password and sends the password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is part of an [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script:

`spawn` opens a new process

`expect` waits for the previous spawned process to output the "expected" string (password in this case)

`send` writes to the spawned process stdin

`EOD` has no meaning in expect, perhaps it is part of another script?

Comment: I think the pasted code snippet should have another EOD prior to it. Here it simply indicates the end of the here doc.